# how to make background process in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Im new in **ionic project**, and i just install 
**ionic cordova plugin** add **cordova-plugin-background-mode**
and then `npm install --save @ionic-native/background-mode`

my goal is i want to make background process in ionic,
and I want to call the function from background process every 1 minutes.

**Q**: How to make it, and where I write that code in app.ts isn't it?

Comment: I suggest you watch some tutorials in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/) there's actually a lot of free tutorials that you can watch.

Comment: any link references of youtube, from you ?

Comment: This plugin will work only if your App is running in background not when the app is closed. just write this code in the first page of your App so the app will not sleep when it goes to background. i.e., network connections will be open to interact with the app.

Comment: can,, you show me what is the best way for the thing I need, sample code..? @PrithiviRaj

Comment: share your usecase like what do you want to do for every one minute. You can do only local notification and push notification for your app if the app is closed. if you want to do something on background you can use pause and resume events.

Comment: i dont understand what u mean,, i only want to insert to sqlite table every 1 minutes, i did `this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.backgroundMode.moveToBackground(); this.MyFunction(); ` and it doesn't work when app is killed